# SearchView is null in second fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, searchview

I have a `ViewPager` with two `Fragments`.

In the `first fragment` load `SearchView` in `Toolbar`.

In the `second fragment` I want to *hide* the `SearchView` and appears another item on the menu.

The problem is when I try to hide the `SearchView` item from the `second fragment` view in `onCreateOptionsMenu` always is *null*.

Before updating the sdk and the android.support libraries to the latest version, from version 22, these methods work correctly.

Fragment number 1:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_view_pager, menu);

    final MenuItem item = (menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, searchView);
    MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(item);
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    ............. 
    .............
  }
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/search_action"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:gravity="start"
        />
   </menu>
```

Fragment number two

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {


    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_edit, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false); 

    /*The top line cause NullPointerException. In debug "action_search" 
     item is in ActionItems, but menu items is empty.*/

    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit);
    disableButtons();
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

That solution there is to this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the error updating **BuildTools (v.25.0.2)** and **AndroidSupportRepository (v.41)**
Also I have used this logic in onPrepareOptionsMenu:

```
  @Override
  public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    toolbar.getMenu().clear();    //remove all items
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_edit);
    menuItem = toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_edit);
 }
```

Before upgrade, not could inflate the menu in this method. Only running menu.clear()

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this line of code in your onCreateView method: setHasOptionsMenu(true);
Add this line in both of your fragments.
If you still can't solve this problem then create a new menu resource for your second fragment class. But I have myself used one menu resource for 10 fragment class , so it should be possible for you too.